# How smart is MongoDB?

Tags: database-design, mongodb

There seems to be almost no documentation about how to design databases for MongoDB. So I thought I'll start by posting my questions here.

Assume this collection (`fruits_inventory`) as an example:

```
{
    "name"      : "Orange",
    "type"      : "citric",
    "available" : 3
}
{
    "name"      : "Apple",
    "type"      : "pome",
    "available" : 0
    "note"      : "Not shipping this month"
}
{
    "name"      : "Pear",
    "type"      : "pome",
    "available" : 2
}
```

`(No indexes set)`

### 1) Field selection

`db.fruits_inventory.findOne({name:"Orange"},{"note":1});`

Will this query seek for a document containing only a field `name` with value `Orange` and return with the first hit, even if it has no `note` field set? Or will it keep searching for a document that does contains a `note` field?

### 2) With unique indexes

If I set a unique index on `name`, would the answer for the previous question change?

> Only these two questions for now. Answers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: I really can't because the query will return NULL in either cases. How else could I test it?

Comment: there is no documentation about how to design: not true. but also quite irrelevant here. you need the docs about querying, and that's well documented. and btw.. no results for those queries.. does that tell you something? what else could you test?

Comment: > I really can't because the query will return NULL in either cases - You really should just try it...

Comment: @BernieHackett: Of course I tried it, I used the PHP driver and I just kept getting NULL which makes sense because the field I requested was not found in either cases.

Comment: But the _id field is always returned, as you can see below, unless you explicitly exclude it, which you didn't do here.  I suspect you're really having a problem with using the PHP driver.  The PHP code fragment concerned might have gotten you help with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote the following script:

```
// sofruit.js
db = db.getSiblingDB('test');

db.fruits_inventory.drop();
db.fruits_inventory.save({
    "name"      : "Orange",
    "type"      : "citric",
    "available" : 3
});
db.fruits_inventory.save({
    "name"      : "Apple",
    "type"      : "pome",
    "available" : 0,
    "note"      : "Not shipping this month"
});
db.fruits_inventory.save({
    "name"      : "Pear",
    "type"      : "pome",
    "available" : 2 
});

var a1 = db.fruits_inventory.findOne({name:"Orange"},{"note":1});

db.fruits_inventory.ensureIndex({name:1}, {unique:true});

var a2 = db.fruits_inventory.findOne({name:"Orange"},{"note":1});
```

Then I ran it from the mongo shell and got:

```
> load('../mongojs/sofruit.js');
> a1
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e7d119e9b3e59bf2e0c5199") }
> a2
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e7d119e9b3e59bf2e0c5199") }  
>
```

So, the answer is "Yes," it will return the first hit, even if it has no "note" field set.  Adding an index doesn't change that.

Answer (score 3):

You can connect directly to mongodb and check it:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.0
connecting to: test
> use test
switched to db test
> db.fruits_inventory.save({
...     "name"      : "Orange",
...     "type"      : "citric",
...     "available" : 3
... });
> db.fruits_inventory.save({
...     "name"      : "Pear",
...     "type"      : "pome",
...     "available" : 2
... })
> db.fruits_inventory.save({
...     "name"      : "Apple",
...     "type"      : "pome",
...     "available" : 0,
...     "note"      : "Not shipping this month"
... })
> db.fruits_inventory.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e7d0fa5626e0ab7b5074bb0"), "name" : "Orange", "type" : "citric", "available" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e7d101b626e0ab7b5074bb1"), "name" : "Pear", "type" : "pome", "available" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e7d1059626e0ab7b5074bb2"), "name" : "Apple", "type" : "pome", "available" : 0, "note" : "Not shipping this month" }
> db.fruits_inventory.find({name: "Orange"},{"note":1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e7d0fa5626e0ab7b5074bb0") }
> db.fruits_inventory.ensureIndex({name:1}, {unique:true})
> db.fruits_inventory.find({name: "Orange"},{"note":1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e7d0fa5626e0ab7b5074bb0") }
```

So in answer to your question, when you query for the note field, it will just return the id and having a unique index makes no difference.

Comment: Not sure quite what you mean "it will just return the index" -- perhaps "it will use the index [to service the query]"?

Comment: Thank you =) From the PHP API (That's what I used) I just kept getting NULL.